# Error java.lang.runtimeexception view is not a sliding drawer

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, view

Hi I have been creating an app that implements a cutom sliding navigation drawer. However, I keep on receiving an error shown on the title.

Logs:

```
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mobextph.krispykreme/com.mobextph.krispykreme.ParentActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{5321e6b8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f090002 app:id/left_drawer} is not a sliding drawer
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View android.widget.LinearLayout{5321e6b8 V.E..... ......ID 0,0-0,0 #7f090002 app:id/left_drawer} is not a sliding drawer
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1170)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at com.mobextph.krispykreme.ParentActivity.changeFragment(ParentActivity.java:141)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at com.mobextph.krispykreme.ParentActivity.onCreate(ParentActivity.java:111)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
10-30 15:38:20.510: E/AndroidRuntime(1863):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
```

The Main Activity class is:

```
package com.mobextph.krispykreme;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mobextph.krispykreme.constants.Constants;

import android.R.color;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class ParentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private Fragment changedFragment= null;
    private FragmentManager fm;

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;

    private ArrayList<String> navDrawerItems;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    private String[] menuItem= {"ORDER", "STAMP CARD", "REWARDS", "STORES", "FAVORITES"};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//        Drawable d;
//        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent)));
        /*Slider*/
        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
        navMenuTitles= menuItem;

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.drawer_list_item, R.id.title, menuItem));

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.button_menu, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
//          changeFragment(-1);
        }
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

//        DatabaseHandler db= new DatabaseHandler(this);
//      
//      for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
//          db.insertFavorite(Constants.id[i], Constants.imageItem[i],
//                  Constants.title[i], Constants.price[i], Constants.desc[i],
//                  Constants.status[i]);
//      }

        changeFragment(-1);
    }

    public void changeFragment(int fragment){

        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        changedFragment = null;

        switch(fragment){
        case -1:
            changedFragment = new HomeFragment();
//          mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            break;
        case Constants.ORDER_SCREEN_CLICKED:
            changedFragment = new OrderFragment();
            break;
        case Constants.FAVORITES_SCREEN_CLICKED:
            changedFragment = new FavoritesFragment();
            break;
        }

        if (changedFragment != null) {
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_holder, changedFragment);
            transaction
                    .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(fragment, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(fragment);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(linearLayout);
        }
    }

    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            int fragment = 0;
            if(position == 0)
                fragment= Constants.ORDER_SCREEN_CLICKED;
            else if(position == 4)
                fragment= Constants.FAVORITES_SCREEN_CLICKED;

            changeFragment(fragment);
        }

    }


//    @Override
//    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//        return true;
//    }
//
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
//        int id = item.getItemId();
//        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
//            return true;
//        }
//        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if(mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            default: return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

The view code that shows a linear layout for the sliding drawer and a listview is:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#008265"
        android:gravity= "left" >

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_login"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="LOGIN"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="0dp"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="|"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textSize="15dp"/>

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="SIGN UP"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:paddingLeft="0dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/list_divider"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
            android:gravity= "left" />


    </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: what is the error you getting??post your logcat

Answer (score 1):

Try setting

```
layout_gravity="start" or layout_gravity="left"
```

in your left_drawer instead of gravity

Comment: hm documentations says you just need gravity set to be left or start for a layout to be a sliding view. Dunno why its still throwing an error there.